# creating sign in only views/methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I created a user model using devise. I was wondering how can I create views and methods that only work after I've signed in?

Here is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :rememberable, :validatable

end
```

controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def create
    User.create(user_params)
  end

  private

    def user_params
      # required input for params
      # permit - returns a version of the params hash with ony the permitted attributes
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be protecting controllers and it's actions.

```
before_action :authenticate_user!

user_signed_in?

current_user

user_session
```

read more!

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise